# Safari margin percentage error

Tags: css, cross-browser, safari, position, margin

Everything works fine in Firefox and chrome when i give margin in percentage with absolute position
`margin:50% 0 0 60%;position:absolute;z-index:5;`.

FF/chrome calculating the percentage according to the screen size . but In safari it seems to be calculating margin percentage to the total height of the body(Not sure!).so i tried calc() with vw

`margin:calc(50vw * 0.54) 0 0 calc(50vw * 0.60);position:absolute;z-index:5;`

No effect in safari.I think i'm missing something .please help

EDIT:
Added jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xjSx3/3/ please see the difference between ff/chrome and safari

Answer (score 0):

`calc()` is only supported by the most recent version of Safari (with `-webkit-` prefix)

http://caniuse.com/calc

and viewport units are only partially supported, meaning there can be weird behaviour

http://caniuse.com/viewport-units

Comment: Thanks for the info,but the problem not solved with direct margin percentage in safari?!

Comment: Sorry - didn't make it clear enough what I meant. The point was that using calc and viewport-units is unreliable, and perhaps you should try and find another method to achieve what you need? Besides, the first line you posted seems to be working in exactly the same way in Chrome (v 30.0.1599.101) and Safari (v 6.0.5) http://jsfiddle.net/xjSx3/ - what exactly is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: Hi benedikt,thanks again for the effort&help ,i have modified the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xjSx3/3/ to look as mine. you can see the margin difference between ff/chrome and safari.you can see the margin looks to be doubled than ff/chrome.I'm totally stuck in this issue.

Comment: Why are you using margins though? Shouldn't you be using top/left/right/bottom? See updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xjSx3/5/

Comment: the overlay div is clickable with a jquery function ,if we use top/left/right we can't click.i think you should see my site , http://192.185.56.215/~wwwtheam/demo/lookbook.html